# saving multiple outputs in different files

Tags: python, filesystems, store, gnuplot

I have a program which generates several plots.. Now I need to save each plot in a different file like say: file1, file2, file2,...

P.S: I am using Gnuplot to save and generate the plots:

g('set output \"test.ps\"')

How do I generate these names?

Comment: Generating the strings should be easy if you're familiar with Python, what part are you having issues with?

Comment: in the code: g('set output \"test.ps\", I need to keep saving files as test1, test2, test2.. This just generates all graphs with the name test.ps

Comment: use `g('set output \"test%d.ps\"' % n)`, and make n increase.

Comment: @Thomas, post your answer as an answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use string formatting. The simplest option is to use

```
g('set output \"test%d.ps\"' % n)`
```

and make n increase.